# До ввода пробела компонент TextArea не получает текст

Tags: qt, qml

Qt 5.12.3 Qml компонент TextArea поведение на Android (Android 8 c оболочкой MIUI).
При вводе текста компонент TextArea не получает событие onTextChanged с введенным текстом до момента ввода пробела. Можно ли это вылечить?

```
TextArea {
    onTextChanged: console.log("onTextChanged:", text)
}
```

При вводе пробела в логе можно видеть сообщение

```
W MyApp: {default} [W] [28.08.19 17:38:54.738] Input method out of sync "" 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, есть свойство preeditText, которое содержит текст до ввода пробела. Для получения текущего текста сделал так

```
property string commentText: idCommentInput.text.length > idCommentInput.preeditText.length
                                    ? idCommentInput.text
                                    : idCommentInput.preeditText
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
TextArea 
{
    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText;
    onTextChanged: { console.log("onTextChanged:", text) }
}
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#inputMethodHints-prop

Comment: ImhNoPredictiveText не помогало. Нашел свойство preeditText у TextArea - содержит нужный текст.